# gisgraphy geocoder - importing custom data

Tags: geocoding, gisgraphy

I have been researching offline geocoders - and am impressed with what I've seen in [Gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com/).  It is especially attractive to my environment, since I am on Windows Server 2008 and Apache Tomcat.  Nominatim is also very robust - but will be too much of a challenge to stand up in this environment given my current schedule and resources.

I have a few 'custom' datasets that I would like to add to gisgraphy: polyline streets and address points.  I haven't found any usable instructions to accomplish this.  I poked around in the PostGIS db, SOLR stuff, and even source code to see if the access point(s) were easily identifiable - but I'm afraid not.

Has anyone loaded custom datasets into gisgraphy?  Any pointers on how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is too way to do this.

first, you create a csv files with the csv format described on http://download.gisgraphy.com/openstreetmap/ and put it on the data/import/openstreetmap. note that the file must be named XX.txt (two letters.txt) and no allcountries file should be present in the directory (if it is the case, the other files are ignored)

second way , you use the admin UI, you can also use a little script with CURL to run batch and post data as the HTML form will. See some screenshots at http://www.gisgraphy.com/screenshots.htm.

prefer the second, since the importer can only been run once

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.  Excellent work with gisgraphy - thanks for sharing!